# Is there a "self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight"like method for collection cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to make self resizing cells for my collection view. Ill display text parts and those text parts have many sizes, since every cell will have a paragraph. Reading a guide on appcoda and useyourloaf i got the solution to make it with table view, so the only thing i can't do on the collection view cell is this

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight
```

for obvious reasons I can't use it on collection view. Is there any similar thing that I can do for collectionView cells?

PS: I can't change the collection for a tableView.
PS2: I'm using swift

Comment: There is self sizing cells for collectionview. Watch wwdc 2014 session for that. The session is around 'What's new in TableView and CollectionView' and introduces clean self sizing cells for both.

Comment: @MartinKoles Except that it doesn't actually _work_ for collection views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory there is; Apple has been claiming since WWDC 2014 that there are self-sizing collection view cells in exactly the same way as for self-sizing table view cells.

But *in fact* every time I try this feature, my app crashes. So in my view the answer is: no, if you want dynamically sized collection view cells you will have to size them dynamically yourself. This is not difficult, however. Just implement `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` and set the size of the item. If you want it to be based on internal constraints, call `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:` here.

Comment: Example downloadable project here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch08p466collectionViewFlowLayout2/ch21p748collectionViewFlowLayout2/ViewController.swift

Comment: Than you very much, I'm trying to make it work with the code you posted =D!

Comment: @user3047134 It isn't just code; it's a downloadable project. It does work. Download it and run it. You'll see.

Comment: don't remember set UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

Comment: @ИсмаилХасбулатов Yes, it's set in the storyboard.